# Examining multidimensional array passed to a function in gdb

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array, gdb

I have written code for dynamic programming, matrix chain multiplication algorithm. For this question, I am not concerned with the implementation details of algorithm.

I am trying to debug it using **gdb**. However, I am having a hard time examining `cost_table` 2-D array inside `matrix_chain_order` function.

Inside `matrix_chain_order` function, I set a breakpoint and examine the `cost_table` 2-D array. I have also used `printf` statements there.
The `printf` statements print the correct value of a cell in `cost_table`.

I found some revelant information in this SO QA: [how to print 2d arry values in gdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19497339/how-to-print-2d-arry-values-in-gdb).

I did not understand what the answer really explained. But it gave me a direction, so I tried printing `cost_table` and its cell values in **gdb**. (Session below)

---

**Code:**

```
/* MATRIX-CHAIN-MULTIPLICATION - CLRS 3rd Edition, Chapter 15 */

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>


#define array_length(arr) (sizeof(arr) == 0 ? 0 : sizeof(arr) / sizeof((arr)[0]));

/* define input sequence to matrix_chain_order function */
const int INPUT_SEQUENCE[] = {4, 10, 3, 12, 20};

/* DEFINE m[i, j]:
 * Let m[i, j] be the minimum number of scalar multiplications needed to compute
 * matrix A_suffix_i..j; for the full problem, the lowest cost way to compute A_suffix_1..n
 * would thus be m[1, n].
 */
/* The function computes the rows from bottom to top and from left to right within
 * each row.
 * It computes each entry m[i, j] using products p_suffix_i-1 * p_suffix_k * p_suffix_j
 * for k = i, i + 1, ...., j - 1 and all entries southwest and southeast from m[i, j].
 *
 * This prodedure assumes that matrix A_suffix_i has dimensions p_suffix_i-1 * p_suffix_i
 * for i = 1, 2, ...., n.
 * Its input is a sequence p = <p_suffix_0, p_suffix_1, ...., p_suffix_n>, where
 * p.length = n + 1.
 *
 * The procedure uses an auxiliary table m[1 ..n, 1 ..n] for storing the m[i, j] costs,
 * and another auxiliary table s[1 ..n - 1, 2 ..] that records which index of k achieved
 * the optimal cost in computing m[i, j].
 */
void matrix_chain_order (int ct_rows, int ct_cols, int cost_table[ct_rows][ct_cols], int kit_rows, int kit_cols, int k_idx_table[kit_rows][kit_cols]);

int main ()
{
  int sequence_len = array_length(INPUT_SEQUENCE);

  /* initialize table (2-D array), m[1 ..n, 1..n] */
  int m = 0, n = 0;
  int cost_table[sequence_len][sequence_len];
  for (m = 0; m < sequence_len; m++) {
    for (n = 0; n < sequence_len; n++) {
      /* m[i, i] = 0, for i = 1, 2, ...., n (the minimum costs for chains of length 1) */
      if (n == m) {
        cost_table[m][n] = 0;
      } else {
        cost_table[m][n] = INT_MAX;
      }
    }
  }

  /* initialize table (2-D array), s[1 ..n - 1, 2..n] */
  int o = 0, p = 0;
  int k_idx_table[sequence_len - 1][sequence_len - 1];
  for (o = 0; o < sequence_len - 1; o++) {
    for (p = 0; p < sequence_len - 1; p++) {
      k_idx_table[o][p] = -1;
    }
  }

  matrix_chain_order(sequence_len, sequence_len, cost_table, sequence_len, sequence_len - 1, k_idx_table);

  return 0;
}

/* NOTE on array passed to the function. */
/* When you pass an array to a function, it decays into a pointer to the first element,
 * at which point knowledge of its size is lost. You need to work it out before decay 
 * and pass that information with the array.
 */
void matrix_chain_order(int ct_rows, int ct_cols, int cost_table[ct_rows][ct_cols], int kit_rows, int kit_cols, int k_idx_table[kit_rows][kit_cols])
{
  int sequence_len = array_length(INPUT_SEQUENCE);

  /* use recurrence,
   *
   * min[i, j] = 0 , if  i = j
   * min[i, j] = min {m[i, k] + m[k + 1, j] + p_suffix_i-1 * p_suffix_k * p_suffix_j , if i < j
   *
   * to compute m[i, i + 1] for i = 1, 2, ...., n - 1 (the minimum costs of chains of length l = 2)
   * during the first execution of the for loop.
   * The second time through the loop, it computes m[i, i + 2] for i = 1, 2, ...., n - 2
   * (the minimum costs for chains of length l = 3), and so forth.
   */
  int chain_len = 0, i = 1, j = 0, k = 0, cost = INT_MAX;
  for (chain_len = 2; chain_len <= sequence_len; chain_len++) {
    for (i = 1; i <= sequence_len - chain_len + 1; i++) {
      j = i + chain_len - 1;

      for (k = i; k <= j - 1; k++) {
        /* at each step, the m[i, j] cost computed depends only on table entries m[i, k] and m[k + 1, j]
         * already computed
         */
        printf("Printed cost_table[%d][%d] : %d\n", i, k, cost_table[i][k]);
        printf("Printed cost_table[%d][%d] : %d\n", (k+1), j, cost_table[k+1][j]);
        cost = cost_table[i][k] + cost_table[k + 1][j] + INPUT_SEQUENCE[i - 1] * INPUT_SEQUENCE[k] * INPUT_SEQUENCE[j];

        if (cost < cost_table[i][j]) {
          cost_table[i][j] = cost;
          k_idx_table[i][j] = k;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**gdb session:**

```
(gdb) p ((int (*) [5][5]) cost_table)[1][1]
$3 = {0, 0, 65280, 0, -8944}
(gdb) p (int [][5]) *cost_table 
$4 = 0x7fffffffdca0
(gdb) p (int [5][5]) *cost_table 
Invalid cast.
(gdb) p (int [][5]) **cost_table 
warning: array element type size does not divide object size in cast
$5 = 0x7fffffffdca0
(gdb) p (int [][5]) *cost_table 
$6 = 0x7fffffffdca0
(gdb) p (int [][5]) cost_table 
warning: array element type size does not divide object size in cast
$7 = 0x7fffffffdbe0
(gdb) p cost_table@5@5
$16 = {{0x7fffffffdca0, 0x500000005, 0x26, 0x100000002, 0x500000001}, {0x7fffffff00000002, 0x4, 0x3, 0x1f7ffe728, 0x7fffffffdca0}, {0x0, 0x5, 0x7fffffffddf0, 0x400952 <main+892>, 0xffffffffffffffff}, {
    0xffffffffffffffff, 0xffffffffffffffff, 0xffffffffffffffff, 0xffffffffffffffff, 0xffffffffffffffff}, {0xffffffffffffffff, 0xffffffffffffffff, 0x0, 0x7fffffffde10, 0x7fffffff00000000}}
(gdb) p *cost_table@5@5
$17 = {{{0, 2147483647, 2147483647, 2147483647, 2147483647}, {2147483647, 0, 2147483647, 2147483647, 2147483647}, {2147483647, 2147483647, 0, 2147483647, 2147483647}, {2147483647, 2147483647, 
      2147483647, 0, 2147483647}, {2147483647, 2147483647, 2147483647, 2147483647, 0}}, {{0, -140389360, 32767, 4, 0}, {0, 0, 65280, 0, -8944}, {32767, 4, 0, 0, 0}, {4, 0, 0, 0, 4}, {0, 0, 0, 4, 0}}, {{
      0, 0, 0, 5, 5}, {4, 4, 5, 4, 0}, {4, 0, -9056, 32767, 3}, {0, 3, 0, -9136, 32767}, {1781326592, 1051810453, 0, 0, 0}}, {{0, 4195552, 0, -8496, 32767}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 4197632}, {0, -140322768, 32767, 
      0, 0}, {-8488, 32767, 0, 1, 4195798}, {0, 0, 0, 1661416990, 1731120}}, {{4195552, 0, -8496, 32767, 0}, {0, 0, 0, -989383138, -1731249}, {-690538978, -1735179, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {4195798, 
      0, 4197744, 0, 0}}}
(gdb) p **cost_table@5@5
$18 = {{0, 2147483647, 2147483647, 2147483647, 2147483647}, {2147483647, 0, 2147483647, 2147483647, 2147483647}, {2147483647, 2147483647, 0, 2147483647, 2147483647}, {2147483647, 2147483647, 2147483647, 
    0, 2147483647}, {2147483647, 2147483647, 2147483647, 2147483647, 0}}
(gdb) p cost_table[i][k] 
Cannot perform pointer math on incomplete types, try casting to a known type, or void *.
```

---

I don't get how the commands that I have used in gdb session result in their respective outputs.

- Why am I unable to use `p cost_table[i][k]` directly in **gdb**,
  whereas the `printf` statements print the result in execution of
  code?
- `p ((int (*) [5][5]) cost_table)[1][1]`: What happens if I change
  value of numbers in this command or if I do something like
  `p ((int(*) [][5]) cost_table)[1][1]`?
- Why is the output of `p *cost_table@5@5` and `p **cost_table@5@5` so
  different?

**My requirement is to be able to examine the `cost_table` and its cells in gdb.**

*Any other suggestions is welcomed.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just ask gbd for it :)

```
Breakpoint 2, matrix_chain_order (ct_rows=5, ct_cols=5, cost_table=0x7fffffffdac0, kit_rows=5, kit_cols=4, k_idx_table=0x7fffffffda80) at delme.c:96
96              printf("Printed cost_table[%d][%d] : %d\n", (k+1), j, cost_table[k+1][j]);
(gdb) ptype cost_table
type = int (*)[5]
(gdb) p ((int (*) [5])cost_table)[i][j]
$12 = 2147483647
```

You may also go up one frame ('up' in gdb) and print directly `cost_table[idx1][idx2]` but it is probably less user friendly to debug in the loop...

the type gdb gives (int(*)[5]) stand for pointer to array 5 of int (see 
https://cdecl.org/?q=int+%28*t%29%5B5%5D if you want to experience the syntax.)

The array type decays that's why only a pointer remains; you may have a look to [Manipulate multidimensional array in a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16943909/manipulate-multidimensional-array-in-a-function) for more explanation in C.

Comment: Please explain the command `p ((int (*) [5])cost_table)[i][j]`?